# I'll pull you in, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> Surrounded by beds, but yet I sleep in the mud,  
> I run to the ocean and dissolve with its foam,  
> From afar I'm unnoticeable, like diamond strings stretching far 
> I'll pull you in and not let go.  
> My current status is powerful and strong.  
> I run far, miles and niles,  
> Like veins to the heart I connect to a source.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are

> water more specially Rivers

Surrounded by beds, but yet I sleep in the mud,

> River beds are a thing and mud is at the bottom of a river.

I run to the ocean and dissolve with its foam,

> Rivers run into oceans and sea foam is mostly water

From afar i'm unnoticeable, like diamond strings stretching far,

> Water is invisible so in a distance it is hard to see. But when you are close you can see the reflection.

I'll pull you in and not let go.

> Water is the "universal solvent".

My current status is powerful and strong.

> Water is powerful when force is added like tsunami or whirlpool.

I run far, miles and niles,

> Rivers are very long (Mostly miles)

Like veins to the heart I connect to a source.

> Rivers runoff to the ocean

Comment: Great job! I think you missed the part where i said "miles and niles" because "niles" was not a spelling error but a reference to a popular river.

Comment: Do u mean nile?

Comment: Yes, thats correct!